# Hamburger menu and bottom tab menu in the same app

Tags: gui-design, mobile, user-research, web

Hello please let me know if this is the wrong place to post this thread.

I just had a heated argument with the owner/project manager of a music web app project we are working on. Being the UI/UX designer and one of two front-end developers in the team, I have sketched, drawn and did all the necessary things to design a user interface for both desktop and mobile. I following web design principles and practices that should be followed (5 months ago and was validated by the whole team)

The problem occurs today while following up on the developer's work so far, I realised that my fellow developer of the team altered the first part of the code that I sent to him and changed the UI as follows:
- I designed the mobile website with a hamburger menu on the top left of the page and coded it as such, however the other developer added a bottom tab menu to the page containing 5 icons. (note that the whole website has exactly 7 categories in the menu)

Now as you can see we have now two menus on the page which I am concerned about.  Once I point this out as a problem and something that should be avoided, the whole team doesn't agree with me and they are actually satisfied with with their solution. The project manager lets me know that that way .. we can have 5 categories on the bottom tab and the other two in the hamburger menu. Which to me doesn't make sense at all, seems wrong and a very very bad User experience. A feeling that I expressed of course but everyone seems to be against me and the project manager refused to let me show him evidence of why doing that is not good web design practice by literally letting me know that he is the boss and I do what he decides. Which of course I didn't take well because I'm not being paid for this (Oh by the way there is also a "Quick access" to 4 categories on the homepage, 4 categories that are also listed in the bottom menu.)

Here is my question guys. Please Am i wrong for thinking that this is bad design and bad User Experience? If No, how can I let them know they are heading in the wrong direction. If Yes, how come I haven't seen websites doing it yet and why does it seems like such a bad design practice.

Please help. Thank you and I apologise in advance if I posted this in the wrong place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Hamburger Vs Menu/Icons

---

The menu wins! Because [Hamburgers Make for Bad UX](https://medium.com/design-philosophies/apple-and-hamburgers-a17e4099fada#.7bd1pje0w).  Studies have shown that many people don't understand it well:

> tested the hamburger with 15 users. 3 got it but thought it was an
>   “Apple” thing.
>   http://www.exquisitetweets.com/collection/lukew/2919

The menus or icons with labels do the best job for everyone. Just like Facebook mobile app.

## Showing some menus upfront and pushing other inside hamburger?

---

I guess they are right, as along as they are **showing the menus upfront that are mostly used**, and hiding the ones that are destructive such as; logout - you don't want your users to leave/stop using your app.

## Multiple access points?

---

That's not a good UX, in fact it will cause more confusion. The users form a specific mental model while using any app, and when they see many options they do get confused.

This post [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/76459/use-of-two-hamburger-menus-in-mobile-app?rq=1) will give you even better insights on hamburger menu.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to real real world of software development.

Design is not the sole responsibility of one person, where they chuck their designs over to the development team - design should be a collaboration involving the whole team and will result in a much stronger solution, and will smooth some of the frictions between you and the team.

For example if they think they are contributing to the design they will be more cooperative. Furthermore, they may make a suggestion which means the solution could be out of the door much faster, or they may make a suggestion which inspires your creative thinking and leads you to come up with a redesign and results in a slightly different but much better solution.

Also as a designer we sometimes need to make a few compromises, e.g. a great design might take 12 months too long to build.

It is absolutely right that you keep an eye on what is being developed, but don't forget that a big part of being UX Designer are the soft skills, like getting along with your colleagues - you are all on the side :-)

As others have said here - bottom menu for the core features, tuck the other minor features under some menu. Let data back up your design direction to prove you right or wrong. Design never ends when the solution goes out the door.

Answer (score 0):

It's about time to add a ...fourth menu! - Just kidding ofc-

Well...

As a principal of design, it's really bad to have two different access points for the same thing. In your case, you have 3 places that someone could navigate and -omg- in the hamburger you have only some additional navigation elements! Also as you describe the hamburger is at the left upper side which is a really bad position for the UX because it is difficult for the thumb to reach out up there.

The best solution I'd suggest and you can see in many mobile apps is the bottom icon/word menu. You show the 4 most used icons and a 3-point -ellipsis - icon to go to the other 3. Period. You have gathered all your navigation in a right explanatory, reachable place and your users are happy.

My 2 cents on it :)

Comment: I like your idea ... all for keeping just one access point and Honestly even though I designed the top left menu it was because they originally asked for that .. I am a big fan of bottom tab menu myself but in this case I ended up accepting the top left menu because i felt like for a music web app it will be too much to have at the same time and all active "The menu tab - the browser tab and the player tab" including the fact that there is a top bar. Isn't it bad the fact that it will reduce what the user is able to see in the page he's actually viewing?

Comment: It is how you arrange the left of your elements. Could the music tab fit in a nice place somewhere else? Do you have to show all menus all the times? What I believe is that you have to test with users, iterate, redesign and retest. As you probably know the UX/UI design is a process and not one time shot. So propose the best you thing and wait the real user feedback. DO NOT CONSIDER DEVELOPERS' FEEDBACK. They leave in their caves and their minds think different :)

Comment: So what you saying is i should just go along with those two menus they want even if it irritates me and makes uncomfortable to work like that ??

Comment: Of course not! What I say is you take the final decision and you support it to death. You're responsible for this and you take any responsibility and negative comments in your back. And as Montero says... F**k you, pay me! And this is what you get paid for :)